# laravel setting up an profile page for the users error Property [user] does not exist on this collection instance

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.7

Im trying to set up a page where an user can add a description about him self for example what kind of hobbies he or she is interrested in so i made a sepperate table from the users, so theres an USER table and a PROFILE table this is how both tables looks

user table

```
 public function up()
 {
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

profile table

```
 public function up()
 {
    Schema::create('profiles', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('user_id');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('firstname');
        $table->string('lastname');
        $table->integer('age');
        $table->integer('birthdate');
        $table->text('bio');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

so whit in mine models i set a relationship to the profile and user whit belognsto()
function in laravel and hasone() this how the model looks

user.php

```
public function profile()

{

    return $this->hasOne(Profile::class);

}
```

profile.php

```
public function user()

{

    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);

}
```

but I get an error when I trying adding this to the blade for example

```
  {{ $profile->user }}
```

its says the variable is unable to be found, so did I not set the relation ships right in laravel that its giving the error or is it someting else

the error is [Property [user] does not exist on this collection instance.]

ProfileController.php

```
public function index()

{
    $profile = Profile::all();

    return view ('profile.show',compact('profile'));

}
```

Comment: Can you perform the reverse? $user->profile? Can you please dump the contents of profile?

Comment: it says Undefined variable: user

Comment: Try to add foreign keys to your profiles table. like 
`$table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();`
`$table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdated('cascade');`

Comment: Okay, are you defining user or profile anywhere? Do you get the signed-in user anywhere?

Comment: yes the user can register or login you want me to add that part to or?

Answer (score 1):

Just as Vahe Shak already mentioned, your profile table needs a foreign key to show user_id is related to id in the users table. Your profile table migration needed to have:

```
$table->integer('user_id');
$table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
```

But editing the migration would not effectively make the changes. Use a new migration

```
php artisan make:migration add_foreign_to_profile
```

Then the migration should be looking like this:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('profiles', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
         $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
    });
}

public function down()
{
    Schema::table('profiles', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->dropForeign('user_id'); 
    });
}
```

Then you can run php artisan migrate